# Socket receive does not release the buffer (byte array)

Tags: c#, sockets, memory-leaks, tcplistener

I'm developing  now a service that listens to messages in TCP protocol, and send them to different destinations.

So I defined a socket , that stays open all the time and gets the messages . the size of the protocol is static and the messages arrive a few at a  time.

The loop runs as long as values are received and cuts the matching size of the messages.

The service works well- all messages are received as needed but the memory gets up and up.
The implementation:

```
public void WaitingForClient()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Accept will block until someone connects
        m_Socket = m_TcpLsn.AcceptSocket();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ReadSocket));
    }
}

//Read the data from the socket
public void ReadSocket(object obj)
{
    Socket s = m_Socket;

    if (s.Connected)
    {
        Byte[] receive = new Byte[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
        try
        {
            // Receive will block until data coming
            // ret is 0 or Exception happen when Socket connection is broken
            int ret = s.Receive(receive, receive.Length, 0);
            while (ret > 0)
            {
                OnMessageRecieved(new RecievedMessage(receive));
                **receive = new Byte[MESSAGE_LENGTH];**
                ret = s.Receive(receive, receive.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            }
        }
```

I saw in net memory profiler that the buffer(a byte array defind in the loop), never gets freed and therefore there is a problem of memory leak. in every sending of a message another instanse of byte array is created & nothing is freed.

I tried to write a loop that initializes the array in nulls that way:

```
try
{
    // Receive will block until data coming
    // ret is 0 or Exception happen when Socket connection is broken
    int ret = s.Receive(receive, receive.Length, 0);
    while (ret > 0)
    {
         OnMessageRecieved(new RecievedMessage(receive));
         for (int i = 0; i < MESSAGE_LENGTH; i++)
         {
             receive[i] = 00;
         }
         ret = s.Receive(receive, receive.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
```

but then part of the messages were sent with nulls instead of the right values(Messages who joined together).

How can I solve it?

Comment: What does OnMessageRecieved do?

Comment: @JonSkeet Very good point, It could be saving the new `RecievedMessage` and therefor all of the buffers as well (assuming the class holds on to receive).

Comment: You should use the value in "ret" to **extract** / copy the data from your "receive" buffer into something else, and pass that to OnMessageReceived().  Then you just leave "receive" as is, instead of creating a new buffer each time.

Comment: This class is used for some projects, so I throw the event and send the current message to the main project.